# WebSocket cross-connection communication (Tornado?)

Tags: websocket, tornado

I'm fumbling around a bit with WebSockets, and was pretty pleased with how easy it was to get a Tornado server running that does basic websocket connections. I've never used Tornado before today, and while I like what I've seen there's a few questions that I have regarding it's use.

Primarily, I'm using WebSockets so that I can have low-overhead communications between two or more client machines. (For the purposes of conversation let's just say it's a chat client) Obviously I can connect into the server from multiple machines, and they can all push messages to the server and the server can respond, which is great! But that's not too much better than your standard AJAX requests. If I have a persistent connection I want to be able to push data to the clients as well. The simplest possible scenario is user 1 posts a message to the server and upon receiving it the server immediately pushes it to user 2.

So what would be a good way to accomplish that? As far as I can see in Tornado there's no way to communicate between connections other than placing the message in a datastore somewhere and having all the other connections poll for new info. That strikes me as terribly clunky though, because all you're really doing at that point is moving the polling process from the client to the server.

Of course, I may be barking up the wrong tree entirely here. It's certainly plausible that Tornado simply isn't the right tool for this job, and if that's the case I'd be happy to hear suggestions for alternatives!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a chat server using tornado, WebSockets and redis: https://gist.github.com/pelletier/532067 (**Updated**: link fixed, thanks @SamidhT)

Comment: Wonderful! That's exactly the type of thing that I was looking for. Seems kinda obvious now that I look at the code, but hindsight is always 20/20, eh? Also, thanks for inadvertently pointing me towards Redis, which was actually the next thing that I was going to go searching for! (Non-volatile memory-based datastore)

Comment: the old link is dead. Here's the new one https://gist.github.com/pelletier/532067

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer has already been accepted: Using a different service still seems very inefficient to me. Why don't you just go with shared memory + conditional variables / semaphores? You sound like you got a standard Consumer-Producer problem